# Heroku and Mailgun - Can I add records to my DNS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, mailgun

Alright, so I deployed my Ruby app to Heroku which I use Mailgun to handle email.

I linked my heroku account and dyno to mailgun. I set up my production.rb and I enter my domain so it can be verified by Mailgun.

To they approve my account I have add some TXT records to my Heroku DNS. But I cannot find where to do it. Is it possible? Or I have to buy my own domain in order to config on GoDaddy (for instance).

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally TXT records can be added/modified by owner of host. Since you deploy application on Heroku, you cannot manage these records yourself.

Instead you probably need to add Mailgun from Heroku's dashboard as add-on. This action doesn't requires any further DNS configuration as far as I remember.
Your account on Mailgun's dashboard will look like 'app123456.mailgun.org' under section 'Sandbox Domains'. All Mailgun environment variables are set-up automatically after adding add-on thus you start sending quickly.
If you already have Mailgun account, I guess, adding Mailgun add-on will overwrite all related environment variables.

Comment: yea I added as an add-on. Still is in 'verified' status my domain. If you are right should be Active from 24 to 48 hs. Thanks, I let you know.

Comment: @EzequielRamiro how it went? Worked after 24 hours? Do I need to create a domain on Mailgun?